# R - quantstrat CSV import for intra-day data

Tags: r, import, xts, quantstrat

I am trying to import data into R for the first time to use in the R package `quantstrat`.  Please see the following:

```
fn1 <- "fgbl_formatted_vpoc_prior_week.txt"
> fn1

> dat <- read.table(file=fn1,sep=",",header=T,as.is=T)
> dat
              Timestamp   Open   High    Low   Last Volume
1   2016-09-27 02:00:00 165.50 165.58 165.46 165.47     2001
2   2016-09-27 03:00:00 165.47 165.65 165.46 165.63     1345
3   2016-09-27 04:00:00 165.64 165.92 165.59 165.91     1241
4   2016-09-27 05:00:00 165.91 166.13 165.91 165.97     880
5   2016-09-27 06:00:00 165.98 165.98 165.76 165.78     748
```

Can someone show how to now get this in a format suitable for `quantstrat` with the correct date/time format which I think is POSIXct.  I am struggling to find any documentation showing how to import this kind of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in wanting time to be in POSIXct format.  Quantstrat uses `xts` objects, which you'll need to create.  You didn't provide an easily reproducible so the first bit of code here generates your data:

```
library(xts)
data <- "
1   2016-09-27 02:00:00 165.50 165.58 165.46 165.47     2001
2   2016-09-27 03:00:00 165.47 165.65 165.46 165.63     1345
3   2016-09-27 04:00:00 165.64 165.92 165.59 165.91     1241
4   2016-09-27 05:00:00 165.91 166.13 165.91 165.97     880
5   2016-09-27 06:00:00 165.98 165.98 165.76 165.78     748"
dat <- read.table(text = data,
                     col.names = c("num", "date", "time", "Open" ,  "High",    "Low",   "Last", "Volume"))
dat <- cbind("Timestamp" = paste(dat$date, dat$time), dat)
# Make dat look just like your example when loaded in R:
dat[, c("num", "date", "time")] <- NULL

# Now have your object, which would be a data.frame:

dat
# Timestamp   Open   High    Low   Last Volume
# 1 2016-09-27 02:00:00 165.50 165.58 165.46 165.47   2001
# 2 2016-09-27 03:00:00 165.47 165.65 165.46 165.63   1345
# 3 2016-09-27 04:00:00 165.64 165.92 165.59 165.91   1241
# 4 2016-09-27 05:00:00 165.91 166.13 165.91 165.97    880
# 5 2016-09-27 06:00:00 165.98 165.98 165.76 165.78    748

posix_times <- as.POSIXct(dat[, 1])
x_dat <- xts(x = dat[, 2:NCOL(dat)], order.by = posix_times)
> x_dat
# Open   High    Low   Last Volume
# 2016-09-27 02:00:00 165.50 165.58 165.46 165.47   2001
# 2016-09-27 03:00:00 165.47 165.65 165.46 165.63   1345
# 2016-09-27 04:00:00 165.64 165.92 165.59 165.91   1241
# 2016-09-27 05:00:00 165.91 166.13 165.91 165.97    880
# 2016-09-27 06:00:00 165.98 165.98 165.76 165.78    748

> class(x_dat)
#[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

`x_dat` is what you can use in `quantstrat`.

PS:

You may find your learning process with `quantstrat` will be a lot faster if you follow a good resource like `http://www.r-programming.org/papers` or the (not free =( ) quantstrat course at datacamp:  `https://www.datacamp.com/courses/financial-trading-in-r`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to convert to POSIXct at all. Import your file with `read.zoo` instead of `read.table`. Assuming  `dat` is a dataframe as in your example

```
> class(dat)
[1] "data.frame"
> dat
         Timestamp   Open   High    Low   Last Volume
1 2016-09-27 02:00 165.50 165.58 165.46 165.47   2001
2 2016-09-27 03:00 165.47 165.65 165.46 165.63   1345
3 2016-09-27 04:00 165.64 165.92 165.59 165.91   1241
4 2016-09-27 05:00 165.91 166.13 165.91 165.97    880
5 2016-09-27 06:00 165.98 165.98 165.76 165.78    748
```

all that is needed is:

```
> dat <- as.xts(read.zoo(dat))
```

check `class`:

```
> class(dat)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

So to go back to your text file all you have to do to import it as  `xts object' is:

dat <- as.xts(read.zoo("yourFileName.txt", arguments needed for your file)

Answer (score 0):

are column names case sensitive there?

cause I noticed that quantmod's chartSeries()

does not like

```
colnames(my_data) <- c('Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Oi')
```

they have to be lower case, like:

```
> class(my_data)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
> tail(my_data)
                       open    high     low   close volume      oi
2016-12-30 10:00:00 2233.50 2234.50 2228.00 2229.25  71515  743254
2016-12-30 10:30:00 2229.25 2234.75 2228.75 2233.75  74937  818191
2016-12-30 11:00:00 2233.75 2235.75 2229.25 2235.00 180772  998981
2016-12-30 11:30:00 2234.75 2237.50 2233.75 2234.75 245717 1244735
2016-12-30 12:00:00 2234.50 2235.25 2233.00 2233.75   6565 1251318
2016-12-30 12:30:00 2233.50 2234.00 2233.25 2233.50    686 1252004
```